# I have two problems with Etch-A-Sketch project

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on Etch-A-Sketch project, but I am stuck on two things since 5 days and I don't seem to progress so I would be glad if someone helps me!

First problem: When I press the Opacity button at the beggining, it works fine, but as soon as I chose Black, Rainbow, Eraser or Clear and then get back go the Opacity, it just draw gray color with 0.1 opacity and it doesn't increse anymore. I tried many things, but without a result.

Second problem: When I chose to apply background color for the grid, it works fine, but when I press the Clear button to reset the grid and try to apply background color again, it doesn't work. In the dev tools it shows me that the background color is changed, but the color is still white and I am a little bit confused.

```js
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const cell = document.querySelector(".grid-item");
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const penCustomColor = document.querySelector("#input-pen-color");
const backgroundCustomColor = document.querySelector("#input-background-color");

let isMouseDown = false;
document.body.onmousedown = () => (isMouseDown = true);
document.body.onmouseup = () => (isMouseDown = false);

function makeGrid(rows, columns) {
  grid.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  grid.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", columns);
  for (i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    grid.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
    chosePenColor(cell);
    choseBackgroundColor();
    clickButtonBlack(cell);
    clickButtonRainbow(cell);
    clickButtonOpacity(cell);
    clickButtonEraser(cell);
    clickButtonClear();
  }
}

makeGrid(15, 15);

function chosePenColor(cell) {
  penCustomColor.addEventListener("input", () => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = penCustomColor.value;
      }
    });
  });
}

function choseBackgroundColor() {
  backgroundCustomColor.addEventListener("input", () => {
    body.addEventListener("click", () => {
      grid.style.backgroundColor = backgroundCustomColor.value;
    });
  });
}

function clickButtonBlack(cell) {
  const buttonBlack = document.querySelector("#btn-black");
  buttonBlack.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "black";
      }
    });
  });
}

function clickButtonRainbow(cell) {
  const buttonRainbow = document.querySelector("#btn-rainbow");
  buttonRainbow.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      const rainbowColors = ["#9400D3", "#4B0082", "#0000FF", "#00FF00", "#FFFF00", "#FF7F00", "#FF0000"];
      const randomColor = rainbowColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * rainbowColors.length)];
      if (isMouseDown) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
      }
    });
  });
}

function clickButtonOpacity(cell) {
  const buttonOpacity = document.querySelector("#btn-opacity");
  buttonOpacity.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        if (this.style.backgroundColor.match(/rgba/)) {
          let currentOpacity = Number(this.style.backgroundColor.slice(-4, -1));
          if (currentOpacity <= 0.9) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = `rgba(0, 0, 0, ${currentOpacity + 0.1})`;
            // this.classList.add("gray");
          }
        } else if (this.style.backgroundColor == "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
          return;
        } else {
          this.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)";
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

function clickButtonEraser(cell) {
  const buttonEraser = document.querySelector("#btn-eraser");
  buttonEraser.addEventListener("click", () => {
    cell.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
      if (isMouseDown) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = "";
        // cell.style.opacity = 1;
      }
    });
  });
}

function clickButtonClear() {
  const buttonClear = document.querySelector("#btn-clear");
  buttonClear.addEventListener("click", () => {
    grid.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
      child.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
      // child.style.opacity = 1;
    });
  });
}

function createNewGrid() {
  let inputValue = document.querySelector("#grid-size");
  inputValue.addEventListener("input", () => {
    rows = inputValue.value;
    columns = inputValue.value;
  });

  const buttonNewGrid = document.querySelector(".btn-set-grid-size");
  const errorMessage = document.querySelector("#error-message");
  buttonNewGrid.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item").forEach((e) => e.remove());
    if (inputValue.value <= 50) {
      errorMessage.style.opacity = 0;
      makeGrid(rows, columns);
      inputValue.value = "";
    } else {
      errorMessage.style.opacity = 1;
      errorMessage.style.transition = "0.3s ease-in-out";
      inputValue.value = "";
    }
  });
}

createNewGrid();
```

```css
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 95px;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  margin-right: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  margin: 0px;
}

.grid-size {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

label {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.settings {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  gap: 30px;
  width: 200px;
}

#error-message {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ff0000;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.div-pen-color,
.div-background-color {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1>Etch-A-Sketch</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="grid-size">
        <button class="btn-set-grid-size">Set Grid Size</button>
        <input type="text" id="grid-size">
    </div>
    <p id="error-message">Error! Please, enter a number that is less or equal to 50!</p>
    <main class="main-content">
        <div class="settings">
            <div class="div-pen-color">
                <label for="pen-color" class="label-custom-color" id="label-pen-color">Pen Color</label>
                <input type="color" id="input-pen-color" class="input-custom-color">
            </div>
            <div class="div-background-color">
                <label for="background-color" class="label-custom-color" id="label-background-color">Background
                    Color</label>
                <input type="color" id="input-background-color" class="input-custom-color">
            </div>
            <button id="btn-black">Black</button>
            <button id="btn-rainbow">Rainbow</button>
            <button id="btn-opacity">Opacity</button>
            <button id="btn-eraser">Eraser</button>
            <button id="btn-clear">Clear</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid"></div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Still looking at this, but so far: you (re)build the grid with *cells* having a `#ffffff` background color. So, when you set *grid* 'Background Color' and then 'Clear' the grid it only seems not to work as all cell backgrounds are white. Use the `unset` value instead of `#ffffff` in function `clickButtonClear(..)`. Proper answer will follow when I'm done checking...

Comment: Your JS has too many (logic) issues for me to come up with a *bug-free* solution, but you need to use `rgb(...)` colors with **r,g,b,a** parameters consistenly throughout your code, both CSS and JS. This means converting black, white and rainbow colors to rgb(...). Also, you add (as in *not override*) eventlisteners on the fly, this will get you deeper and deeper in trouble. `cell = document.querySelector(".grid-item")` will always return the first grid item. Not sure if I have the time to post an answer addressing all issues in the current JS...

Comment: You can handle drawing by adding a few eventlisteners to `.grid` and use `event.target` to to find and modify cell values. No need to attach events to all the cells. Check [MDN: Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target), esp. the 'Example'.

Comment: Thanks for the advices... I will try to improve the code